# Determine $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $r>0$ so that $0,1,2+i\in \partial B_r(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I'm struggling to see for a method to start this question.
It looks like a question related with mobius transforms.
We have studied about determining the mobius transform when points from the domain are given. For example, getting the cross ratio.

But here I don't see any points from the domain and also a method to determine the center when the mobius transform is given.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: $r$ can be anything greater than half the distance from $0$ to $2+i$.

Comment: Can you please explain how should I proceed afterwards

Comment: Given $r$, $z$ could be anything in the intersection of the disks of radius $r$ around $0$, $1$ and $2+i$.

Comment: On the other hand, you could first choose any $z$, and then let $r$ be greater than the maximum of $|z|$, $|z-1|$ and $|z-(2+i)|$.

Comment: Oh @RobertIsrael I'm sorry. The question refers to  the boundary of the ball. (I edited it now)

Comment: OK, so you want $z$ to be equidistant from $0$, $1$ and $2+i$.  Construct the perpendicular bisectors of the line segments $[0,1]$ and $[1, 2+i]$, and see where they intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $z = x +iy$ you have the three equations

1. $\lvert z - 0 \rvert = r$. i.e. $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
2. $\lvert z - 1 \rvert = r$, i.e. $(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = x^2  - 2x + 1 + y^2 = r^2$
3. $\lvert z - (2+i) \rvert = r$, i.e. $(x - 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2 = (x - 2)^2  + y^2 - 2y + 1 = r^2$

Subtracting 2.from 1. you get $2x - 1 = 0$, hence $x = \frac{1}{2}$. Thus $y^2 = r^2 - \frac{1}{4}$. Inserting this in 3. yields $\frac{9}{4} + r^2 - \frac{1}{4} - 2y +1 = r^2$ which means $y = \frac{3}{2}$.

Then you get $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{9}{4} = r^2$, i.e. $r = \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$.